# How to link g++ -> g++-4.6 to -4.7

Tags: c++, ubuntu

i would like to change g++ -> g++-4.6 to -4.7 but invain how can i handle this situation .

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Sep  3 18:28 cpp -> cpp-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 306200 Apr 16  2012 cpp-4.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 527596 Apr 22 02:14 cpp-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Mar 14  2012 g++ -> g++-4.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 310296 Apr 16  2012 g++-4.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 527596 Apr 22 02:15 g++-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Sep  3 18:28 gcc -> gcc-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 306200 Apr 16  2012 gcc-4.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 527596 Apr 22 02:17 gcc-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  21988 Apr 22 02:17 gcc-ar-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  21988 Apr 22 02:17 gcc-nm-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  21988 Apr 22 02:17 gcc-ranlib-4.7
root@sudeep-Inspiron-1545:/usr/bin# ls -l g++
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar 14  2012 g++ -> g++-4.6
root@sudeep-Inspiron-1545:/usr/bin# ln -s g++-4.7 g++
ln: failed to create symbolic link `g++': File exists
root@sudeep-Inspiron-1545:/usr/bin#
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version

Comment: all experts were once beginner@downvote

Comment: All people can use a search engine.  I have no interest in your subject and yet managed to find a reasonable answer in seconds.  Why couldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the existing link first:

```
rm g++
```

But, you should probably just use [update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) instead.